# MongoDB, How can I migrate database to new cluster with higher version without an outage

Tags: migration, mongodb

We are having our mongodb cluster at AWS and our production DB mongo is very old - we are still using version 2.6 then latest version at the moment is 3.2.7. We need to upgrade mongodb binaries to the latest version.
We can't upgrade existing DB cluster right in place because of versions incompatibility, new storage engine and ITSec requirements to encrypt EBS volumes. 
That means we need to setup new DB cluster v.3.2 and somehow migrate existing data on it. We have to do this without an outage because DB outage means that whole production delivery stack will be down.

Any idea how I can do it without an outage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to add new 3.2 node to current replica set (votes:0), then wait as it syncs.
Now we can shutdown one 2.6 instance and set for current 3.2 votes:1

Next we can work with another 3.2 and wait for sync....

So replacing one by one is a safest way and provide full security.

Have a fun!